# Can Magit be configured to NOT touch/read every buffer in Emacs?

Tags: magit, tramp

**Summary:**

Magit is constantly forcing my tramp/ssh buffers to connect remotely to their source machines. The buffers are all unrelated to the repo I'm working with. How do I stop this? The tramp/ssh buffers *do* contain git-versioned files.

**Backstory:**

I have a number of tramp/ssh buffers open in my Emacs to a virtual machine. Due to a years-old bug in VMware Fusion, I must close it before putting my laptop to sleep or Fusion crashes my entire laptop. I leave the Emacs buffers open because they'll reconnect to the VM after restarting it. I don't close the tramp/ssh files because my desktop setup doesn't seem to restore tramp buffers on a restart of Emacs, and I spent a lot of time finding each of those files among thousands of files.

**Problem:**

If I try to use Magit on a local repo unrelated to my VM work, it causes all of my tramp buffers to try to re-connect and tramp blocks Emacs until it succeeds or fails.

** Backtrace (toggle-debug-on-quit): **

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  signal(quit nil)
  byte-code("\302\303\"\210\304 @   A\"\207" [vec err tramp-cleanup-connection t signal] 3)
  tramp-maybe-open-connection(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil])
  tramp-send-command(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil] "echo \\\"`getconf PATH 2>/dev/null`\\\" 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?")
  tramp-send-command-and-check(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil] "echo \\\"`getconf PATH 2>/dev/null`\\\"")
  tramp-send-command-and-read(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil] "echo \\\"`getconf PATH 2>/dev/null`\\\"" noerror)
  tramp-get-remote-path(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil])
  tramp-get-remote-readlink(["ssh" nil "and" "/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" nil])
  tramp-sh-handle-file-truename("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  apply(tramp-sh-handle-file-truename "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  tramp-sh-file-name-handler(file-truename "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  apply(tramp-sh-file-name-handler file-truename "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  byte-code("\300\301\215\207" [suppress (apply foreign operation args)] 2)
  byte-code("K\306\211<\203\237\n@\307=\203\237\306\310\311!\203\"\312\311\313N@!\206\221\314\315!\2039\316\315!\2044\317\315!\205\221\315 \202\221\320\321!\211\205D\322\f!)\203P\323\320\321!!\202\221\320\324!\211\205[\322\f!)\203g\323\320\324!!\202\221\320\325!\211\205r\322\f!)\203~\323\320\325!!\202\221\326\327!\203\212\323\327!\202\221\330\331!\210\323\332!)\333\n\211A@\262\334\335#\210)\336\337\215\211\336=\203\312*\340\341+,BC-./0\306\342\343\217,\210\344+,\"\202\374    \345=\203\373\3061*\346\347+,BC-./0\306\342\343\217,\210\350*\351\"\210\344+,\")\202\374    *\207" [foreign result sf file-name-handler-alist d default-directory nil autoload boundp temporary-file-directory eval standard-value fboundp temp-directory subrp functionp getenv "TEMP" file-directory-p file-name-as-directory "TMP" "TMPDIR" file-exists-p "c:/temp" message "Neither `temporary-file-directory' nor `temp-directory' is defined -- using /tmp." "/tmp" load noerror nomessage non-essential (byte-code "\300\301\215\207" [suppress (apply foreign operation args)] 2) 5 "Non-essential received in operation %s" (byte-code "   X\205g\306 \307\216\203;\310X\203;\311\312\313U\203!\314\2026\315U\203+\314\2026\316U\2035\317\2026\320\fP
#\210   \321Y\205f\322!\203S\313\323\324\325#)\326!\205f\311\327\330\331\"\fP
$*\207" [level tramp-verbose save-match-data-internal tramp-message-show-message fmt-string arguments match-data ((byte-code "\301\302\"\207" [save-match-data-internal set-match-data evaporate] 3)) 3 apply message 0 "" 1 2 "Warning: " "Tramp: " 4 processp tramp-get-connection-property "vector" nil vectorp tramp-debug-message format "(%d) # " vec-or-proc] 6) ((error)) tramp-run-real-handler suppress 1 "Suppress received in operation %s" tramp-cleanup-connection t v operation args arguments fmt-string level vec-or-proc tramp-message-show-message] 6)
  tramp-file-name-handler(file-truename "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  file-truename("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c")
  file-in-directory-p("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/")
  apply(file-in-directory-p ("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/"))
  tramp-run-real-handler(file-in-directory-p ("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/"))
  tramp-sh-file-name-handler(file-in-directory-p "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/")
  apply(tramp-sh-file-name-handler file-in-directory-p ("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/"))
  byte-code("\300\301\215\207" [suppress (apply foreign operation args)] 2)
  byte-code("K\306\211<\203\237\n@\307=\203\237\306\310\311!\203\"\312\311\313N@!\206\221\314\315!\2039\316\315!\2044\317\315!\205\221\315 \202\221\320\321!\211\205D\322\f!)\203P\323\320\321!!\202\221\320\324!\211\205[\322\f!)\203g\323\320\324!!\202\221\320\325!\211\205r\322\f!)\203~\323\320\325!!\202\221\326\327!\203\212\323\327!\202\221\330\331!\210\323\332!)\333\n\211A@\262\334\335#\210)\336\337\215\211\336=\203\312*\340\341+,BC-./0\306\342\343\217,\210\344+,\"\202\374    \345=\203\373\3061*\346\347+,BC-./0\306\342\343\217,\210\350*\351\"\210\344+,\")\202\374    *\207" [foreign result sf file-name-handler-alist d default-directory nil autoload boundp temporary-file-directory eval standard-value fboundp temp-directory subrp functionp getenv "TEMP" file-directory-p file-name-as-directory "TMP" "TMPDIR" file-exists-p "c:/temp" message "Neither `temporary-file-directory' nor `temp-directory' is defined -- using /tmp." "/tmp" load noerror nomessage non-essential (byte-code "\300\301\215\207" [suppress (apply foreign operation args)] 2) 5 "Non-essential received in operation %s" (byte-code "   X\205g\306 \307\216\203;\310X\203;\311\312\313U\203!\314\2026\315U\203+\314\2026\316U\2035\317\2026\320\fP
#\210   \321Y\205f\322!\203S\313\323\324\325#)\326!\205f\311\327\330\331\"\fP
$*\207" [level tramp-verbose save-match-data-internal tramp-message-show-message fmt-string arguments match-data ((byte-code "\301\302\"\207" [save-match-data-internal set-match-data evaporate] 3)) 3 apply message 0 "" 1 2 "Warning: " "Tramp: " 4 processp tramp-get-connection-property "vector" nil vectorp tramp-debug-message format "(%d) # " vec-or-proc] 6) ((error)) tramp-run-real-handler suppress 1 "Suppress received in operation %s" tramp-cleanup-connection t v operation args arguments fmt-string level vec-or-proc tramp-message-show-message] 6)
  tramp-file-name-handler(file-in-directory-p "/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/")
  file-in-directory-p("/ssh:and:/android/out/RDM/output/android_os_build/kernel_imx/drivers/video/mxc/mxc_hdmi.c" "/Users/hchapman/work/RDM/")
  magit-revert-buffers()
  magit-refresh()
  call-interactively(magit-refresh nil nil)
  command-execute(magit-refresh)
```

Comment: What's your `magit-revert-buffers` set to?

Comment: How do you know it's Magit doing it?

Comment: @npostavs: I haven't configured magit in any way. It is set to `usage`. Also, I'm using `Magit 20151105.1932, Git 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60), Emacs 24.5.1`

Comment: @tarsius: because if I hit `g` in the magit-status buffer, it does it.

Comment: According to the docs, it should only be reverting buffers belonging to the current repo. None of my tramp buffers are files in the same repo.

Comment: Can you get a backtrace by `toggle-debug-on-quit` and `C-g` while Emacs is stuck on tramp reconnecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that ultimately `tramp-sh-handle-file-truename` is called which needs to make remote connections.

(Previously Tramp also tries to handle `file-in-directory-p` itself but since it eventually figures out that it does not implement a handler for that function and just falls back to the vanilla `file-in-directory-p`, that doesn't cause any remote connections. Except that `file-in-directory-p` does call `file-truename` and that, as stated earlier, *does* make remote connections.)

This patch was applied (will be part of v2.3.1) to fix this issue:

```
diff --git a/lisp/magit-mode.el b/lisp/magit-mode.el
index 271cc5f..d187cf5 100644
--- a/lisp/magit-mode.el
+++ b/lisp/magit-mode.el
@@ -833,6 +833,8 @@ (defun magit-revert-buffers (&optional force)
                   (--filter
                    (let ((file (buffer-file-name it)))
                      (and file
+                          (equal (file-remote-p file)
+                                 (file-remote-p topdir))
                           (file-in-directory-p file topdir)
                           (member (file-relative-name file topdir) tracked)))
                    (buffer-list))
```

This checks whether the `file` (each file which is being visited in some buffer in turn) and the directory/repository `topdir` are located on the same remote (`nil` for the local machine) before checking whether the file is located inside that directory. Obviously a file cannot possibly be located inside a directory which isn't even located on the same machine, so in that case we can bail before performing the more expensive check.

Comment: Arguably, Tramp should perform this optimization.  I suggest you report this to Michael Albinus.

Comment: Thank you! The patch worked. By "report," did you mean just report back here or also to report the behavior to tramp/emacs/other?

Comment: @Stefan: Agreed, I was going to suggest the same. #Harvey: Well, what I originally meant was that you should test the patch and let me know whether it worked for you (don't see why it wouldn't, but making sure cannot hurt). But now I am with Stefan and think you should "report" (as in "suggest that he adds this optimization") this to Michael (on https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/tramp-devel/). I'll apply this patch anyway.

Comment: @tarsius: will do.